# Best way to launch a linux/unix command from C Language

Tags: linux, unix, c

After doing some research i came here, just wanted to know what is the better way to launch a command(for both input/out controlled & not controlled scenarios) in C language.

I have looked at the `system`, `popen` and `fork`

while `popen` and `fork` are overhead/heavy weight ( since use of pipes in former and duplicating whole parent process in later) and `system` is non portable.

Thanks for any advices.

**Update 1**

But COW works if either process tries to modify common variable, we need to take a lot of care not to allow such a thing, but for my requirement i can use few existing commands like grep,awk,dd and find. Also launching another exe, i find system very convenient , but some times i will have to capture the output, so other than system ,do we have some other alternate

Comment: Many *nix have an optimized fork that does copy-on-write, so the cost isn't that high. That's moot as popen(3) and system(3) will both use fork(2) (or an equivalent system call, depending on which *nix) anyway.

Comment: "some times i will have to capture the output" save the output to file then use c to read it. https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file (just fyi, I use system.)